# Termcolor installs succesfully but doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: python, module, termcolor

I started learning Python recently. I am trying to use the termcolor module. I installed it (latest version) successfully. But it doesn't seem to work on Pycharm. I apply the example code that is provided in the module download page (as listed below) and I get only one colored word as output (as in the image). Do you know what can cause this?

code page: https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/

```
import sys

from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored("Hello, World!", "red", attrs=["reverse", "blink"])
print(text)
cprint("Hello, World!", "green", "on_red")

print_red_on_cyan = lambda x: cprint(x, "red", "on_cyan")
print_red_on_cyan("Hello, World!")
print_red_on_cyan("Hello, Universe!")

for i in range(10):
    cprint(i, "magenta", end=" ")

cprint("Attention!", "red", attrs=["bold"], file=sys.stderr)
```

[Output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvTJF.png)

I expected to have all the colors and formatting listed in the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in colored switch parameter force_color to True

such as

```
print(colored('answer' , 'red' , None , None , no_color = False , force_color = True))
```

Answer (score -1):

your code run correctly in vcs like this :[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm0K3.png)

also use colorama library for showing colors in Pycharm terminal